# How to make Eclipse SVN/Team Synchronize work like command line SVN?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

How do I get Eclipse Team Synchronize (for SVN) to only commit files that are under version control when I perform an svn commit? This is the default behavior for most subversion client tools but does not seem to be the case for Eclipse. Eclipse recursively adds ALL files which is the last thing I want. I also do not want to manually deselect files on every commit. I know there are ways to put in filters to ignore certain file types but that is not what I want either. I would be shocked if this very basic functionality is not doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Upgrade to a newer version of Eclipse (greater than 3.6 at least).

Long answer: I was using Eclipse 3.6. To my knowledge there is no way to accomplish this. With Eclipse 4.2 there is a selection under Preferences --> SVN (or team synch) to deselect all new files prior to commit. This is what I needed.